# Help with finding an equation to work out the length of cable required to produce loss of colour on an analogue video signal

Tags: reflection, electrical-engineering, distance

When I briefly taught Broadcast Engineering I set up an experiment in order to demonstrate the effect of signal reflections along coaxial cable on an analogue PAL waveform.

It involved getting the students to work out the precise length of cable needed in order to result in a complete neutralisation of the chroma signal (High frequencies - 4.43MHz) due to the reflections in the cable.

It kept them out of trouble for an hour and the result was immediate and obvious to see as they made up their cable and plugged it from a test signal generator to a scope/Waveform monitor to see if their calculations were correct.

I have long since disposed of my teaching notes and was wondering if any of you could point me to the equation I might have used. It would have involved distance in metres, wavelength and frequency/speed (of light?) I think.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $v=f \lambda$? with velocity $v$, wavelength $\lambda$ and frequency $f$?

Comment: @gonenc: that is a singularly unhelpful comment.

Comment: @JohnRennie Since he is *teaching* the subject I thought it to be appropriate point out but on the second thought it really is unhelpful.

Comment: "When I briefly taught Broadcast Engineering" I failed to add - "A long long time ago - back in the days of diminishing analogue and the dawn of the newfangled digital technology" I am not a teacher, I am a broadcast vision engineer and have not worked with component level engineering principles since my brief stint way back then. I have never done a degree in electrical engineering but have worked in the industry for over 20 years driven by my furious curiosity about how the whole thing works!

Comment: @Klamb I'm utterly sorry for what I've said. Shouldn't have said that.

Comment: Oh, I am also female.

Comment: But I have a sense of humour too and accept the apology of course.

Comment: This isn't my area, but IIRC you only get reflections at impedance changes. In a continuous length of cable you only get reflections where defects in the cable cause an impedance change. Presumably you'd have some empirical defect/metre parameter for your cable.

Comment: Actually it's not obvious why reflections would affect just the colour. Could the colour loss have been to attenuation? The chroma signal is about 3 times the frequency of the luma signal so it may well attenuate more rapidly. Or maybe it's just that reflections reduce the signal to noise and affects the chroma more than the luma.